# Surface area of part of sphere described by an interesting property

Tags: geometry

Let $x, y$, and $z$ be fixed points on the unit sphere and let $R$ be the part of the surface of sphere such that $w \in R$ if and only if the tetrahedron with the vertices $x$, $y$, $z$, and $w$ contains the center of the sphere in its interior. What is the surface area of this region? Will highly appreciate any hints or solutions to the problem.

Comment: At the first glance, you should find antipodes $x', y', z'$ of $x, y, z$, respectively, and the spherical triangle $\triangle x'y'z'$ is $R$. And its area equals that of $\triangle xyz$. But I'm probably wrong...

Comment: The above follows from the observation that $w$ is 'on the edge' when the sphere's centre $S$ is on the surface of the tetrahedron, and this happens when $w$ and $S$ are coplanar with two of the three given points.